# How to use quotes in Command arguments in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm going nuts. I want to spawn this command in rust `git log --grep="foo"`. This works fine from the command line.

So I go ahead and try it like this.

```
Command::new("git")
         .arg("log")
         .arg("--grep=\"foo\"")
         .spawn()
```

That doesn't work.

I can get it to work if I change it to this:

```
Command::new("git")
         .arg("log")
         .arg("--grep=foo")
         .spawn()
```

But this only works because the quotes can be omitted in this simple case so it will run `git log --grep=foo` which is not what I want. I tried plenty of different versions using `format!` etc. I'm pulling my hair out.

I tried to trace it with `dtruss` to figure out what Rust actually ends up using but I also haven't had luck with that. :/

**UPDATE**

Ok, I resolved the issue. It was a bit tricky (for me at least).

The command I wanted to run was `git log --grep="foo|bar" -E`. This needs to have quotes when performed on the command line. But it's also important to note that it needs to be combined with the `-E` parameter.

In Rust however I need to remove the quotes.

```
Command::new("git")
    .arg("log")
    .arg("-E")
    .arg("--grep=foo|bar")
    .spawn()
```

I would still like to know why I have to omit the quotes in Rust.

Comment: What's an example of something that needs the quotes? (I.e. something that doesn't work without internal quotes.) I believe the quoting is all done by the shell and the arguments passed to the executable don't have any quotes (and Rust is passing them directly in the same manner).

Comment: (That is to say, the embedded quotes in the Rust are like writing `--grep='"foo"'` at the shell, i.e. searching for the string `"foo"` verbatim, including the quotes.)

Comment: An `echo --grep="foo"` in the shell confirms that the quotes are interpreted by the shell. They aren't needed when invoking the command from rust.

Comment: Btw, what exactly means "That doesn't work." ? Do you get a compilation error ?

Comment: I updated the answer to lay out the full scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would still like to know why I have to omit the quotes in Rust.

Because you have no shell to interpret them.

When you start the command from shell, you need them, because `git log --grep=foo|bar -E` would be interpreted as piping `git log --grep=foo` to `bar -E`.

Yet, after the shell has interpreted the commands, the arguments `git` receives are effectively `log`, `--grep=foo|bar`, and `-E`.

While invoking the command from Rust, there is no interpretation of the command by a shell, so you don't need the quotes. Putting the quote would the same as running this command from shell

```
git log --grep='"foo|bar"' -E
```

Comment: Oh wow, I'm seriously lacking basic UNIX know how. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

While this is a great answer from Levans, there are also other potential options.

I like the `shell_words` crate, which parses a String containing a full command line into a vector of arguments that can be passed to a Command.

Technically, you'd be able to write

```rust
let cmd=r#"git log --grep="foo""#;
let args = shell_words::split(cmd).unwrap();
```

This inspired me to pack it into a small [cli_runner](https://crates.io/crates/cli_runner) library, which I find useful for testing and getting reports from CLI applications.

Using this, one would write

```rust
let cmd=r#"git log --grep="foo""#;
let output = cli_runner::run(cmd);
assert!(output.status.success());
let so: String = cli_runner::get_stdout(&output);
```